# Plaid Reinitializing Link: Errors occurred

Tags: plaid

Since I'm using Unity Webview as the front end, I have made a redirect URI and registered it when creating a link token. Just following the documentation on: https://plaid.com/docs/link/oauth/#webview

The redirect URI is developed on AWS lambda function, read `link_token` from cookie, read `oauth_state_id` from GET query string. Then using the `302` status code and `"Location"` in `Headers` to redirect back to Plaid.

I believe it works well because I can get the redirect after I finish operations on Bank account.

But I always get an error: `Error: oauth uri does not contain a valid oauth_state_id query parameter. Request ID: juLxa2qy7ZKzZ49`

I'm confused about the error, because my Lambda just copied the oauth_state_id from the request to my redirect URI without any change.

And there are some errors shown in the image. [errors screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IR2hA.png)

This is an example my redirect URI generated: `https://cdn.plaid.com/link/v2/stable/link.html?isWebview=true&token=link-sandbox-02b9e581-c2e1-49d8-b0c0-6ac708535fd1&receivedRedirectUri=https%3A%2F%2Ftdfdfwpj.execute-api.us-west-1.amazonaws.com%2Fdev%2Fplaid-redirect-uri?oauth_state_id=f3d1fe8b-e444-42bb-855a-da5e89a4b796`

Comment: I don't know the answer for this one, but if you don't get an answer on SO, I recommend filing a ticket with Plaid Support and including the `link_session_id` and/or `request_id` in the ticket. With those identifiers, Support can look into exactly what's happening with your redirect and give you a personalized answer.

Answer (score 0):

The error is caused by incorrect use of URLencode, precisely, the whole URL in parameters needs to be encoded.